# SICP Exercise 4.6: Implementing let in the evaluator as a derived expression based on lambda

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, evaluation, sicp

I'm attempting to write a function that transforms a `let` expression of the form:

> ```
> (let ((var1 exp1) ... (varn expn))
>   body)
> ```

Into an (equivalent) `lambda` expression of the form:

> `((lambda (var1 ... varn)    body)  exp1 ... expn)`

Most of the solutions to this problem that I've found appear to be wrong, could someone confirm this is the case?

Take, for example this solution from [SICP answers wiki](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-4.6)

```
 ;; let expression 
 (define (let-vars expr) (map car (cadr expr))) 
 (define (let-inits expr) (map cadr (cadr expr))) 
 (define (let-body expr) (cddr expr)) 

 (define (let->combination expr) 
   (cons (make-lambda (let-vars expr) (let-body expr)) 
         (let-inits expr)))
```

I believe `let->combination` will return a list of this form:

```
((lambda (var1 ... varn) body) (exp1 ... expn))
```

But, what I think it *should* return is a list of this form:

> `((lambda (var1 ... varn)    body)  exp1 ... expn)`

Somehow, shouldn't a call to the [apply function](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html#%28part._apply%29) be used in `let->combination`? How should `let->combination` be modified to include `apply`?

Comment: <hints>(i) what does `(cons 'x '(y1 y2 y3))` return? (ii) What do each of `(make-lambda …)` and `(let-inits expr)` return? (iii) Then what does `(cons (make-lambda …) (let-inits …))` return?</hints>

Comment: All of this is code that you can try out.  Have you tried running these definitions?  Did something about them not work? If something about them doesn't work, please point it out specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I **believe** let-combination will return a list of this form:
>
> ```
> ((lambda (var1 ... varn) body) (exp1 ... expn))
> ```

> But, what I **think** it should return is a list of this form:
>
> ```
> ((lambda (var1 ... varn)    body)  exp1 ... expn)
> ```

There's good news and bad news.  The bad news is that your belief is incorrect.  The good news is that your thought is correct.  That is, you do want the result `((lambda …) …)`, and that's what this code produces.

This Scheme code doesn't require any special interpreter or anything, so you can test this out without any real problem.  Let's look at the definitions again:

```
 (define (let-vars expr) (map car (cadr expr))) 
 (define (let-inits expr) (map cadr (cadr expr))) 
 (define (let-body expr) (cddr expr)) 

 (define (let->combination expr) 
   (cons (make-lambda (let-vars expr) (let-body expr)) 
         (let-inits expr)))
```

So what would happen in `(let->combination '(let ((x 34)) (list x)))`, for instance?  You"ll be evaluating:

```
(cons (make-lambda (let-vars expr) (let-body expr)) 
      (let-inits expr))
```

What do these parts create?  `(make-lambda …)` creates the lambda expression that you'd expect:

```
(lambda (x) (list x))
```

and `(let-inits …)` returns:

```
(34)
```

Now the question is, what is `(cons '(lambda (x) (list x))` '(34))`?  You can test that out easily enough;  it's:

```
((lambda (x) (list x)) 34)
```

This may be a result of some confusion about how `cons` works.  A list is simply either: the empty list, `'()`, or a pair produced by cons whose *car* is an *element* of the list, and whose *cdr* is the *rest* of the list.  Thus:

```
               (cons 1 '())  ;=> (1)
               (cons 1 '(2)) ;=> (1 2)
(cons '(lambda (x) x) '(34)) ;=> ((lambda (x) x) 34)
```

> I believe let-combination will return a list of this form:
>
> ```
> ((lambda (var1 ... varn) body) (exp1 ... expn))
> ```
>
> … Somehow, shouldn't a call to the apply function be used in
>   let-combination? How should let-combination be modified to include
>   apply?

As we've seen, the code actually produces the result that you desired.  If it actually produced something like `((lambda (var1 ... varn) body) (exp1 ... expn))`, then you would probably want to use `apply`.  The simplest way would be to produce

```
(apply (lambda (var1 ... varn) body) (list exp1 ... expn))
```

Note that we've added `apply`, as well as a call to `list`.  This would require changing the definition of `let->combination`.  One possibility would be:

```
(define (let->combination expr) 
   (cons 'apply
         (cons (make-lambda (let-vars expr) (let-body expr)) 
               (cons (cons 'list (let-inits expr))
                     '()))))
```

Another (simpler) option is:

```
(define (let->combination expr) 
   (list 'apply
         (make-lambda (let-vars expr) (let-body expr)) 
         (cons 'list (let-inits expr))))
```

Comment: OP updated the question, it seems that his understanding was correct after all.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I don't see any edits to the question, but maybe it's within the "grace period".  OP stated the a correct *desired* result, but *believes* that the code is incorrect, and that it returns something that it actually doesn't.  It actually returns the correct value.  (This is all very easy to **check**, too.  This really should have just been a case of "put the definitions in the interpreter and see what comes back…".)

Comment: Thank you, as you correctly pointed out, my confusion hinged on my misunderstanding of what cons does (I was conflating it with the list constructor). Indeed, if I'd had the presence of mind to run this on a REPL, could have saved us some time! Thanks.

Comment: @Himerzi Even though languages in the Lisp family are known for list processing capabilities, in most of them there's actually no strict data structure that is a list.  Instead, it's an *intensional* data type.  There is the constant empty list, `'()`, which in many Lisps is the same as the  symbol `NIL`, and there are pairs, constructed by `cons`.  The *convention* is that a list is either: the empty list; or a cons whose car is the first element of the list, and whose cdr is another list (the rest of the list).  So `cons` *is*, in a sense, the list constructor.  The function `list` is just…

Comment: …a useful function defined in terms of it.  `(list x y z) == (cons x (cons y (cons z '())))`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the right form:

```
((lambda (var1 ... varn) body) exp1 ... expn)
```

We're simply calling a function with many arguments, for example:

```
((lambda (var1 var2 var3) (+ var1 var2 var3)) 1 2 3)
=> 6
```

The other form will raise an error, because the interpreter believes that you're trying to apply `1` as a function:

```
((lambda (var1 var2 var3) (+ var1 var2 var3)) (1 2 3))
=> expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
```

Perhaps you're confused about the way `let` works? for instance, this expression:

```
(let ((x 1)
      (y 2))
  (+ x y))
```

Is just syntactic sugar and it'll get transformed to this equivalent expression:

```
((lambda (x y)
   (+ x y))
 1 2)
```

The above is a procedure application, and that's something the evaluator can understand and well, evaluate. As stated in SICP, the evaluation of a `let` expression requires two steps: first we transform the expression into a `lambda` application, and *then* we pass the resulting transformation to the evaluator, for normal evaluation. So no, you should not add an `apply` inside the transformation, let the existing code in the evaluator take care of that, you just have to emit an expression that the evaluator can understand.